# Erro com Fragments

Tags: android, android-fragment

Sou iniciante na programação Android e estou tendo um erro que não consigo solucioná-lo.

Estou fazendo um projeto que utiliza fragments. Tenho um pequeno layout que funciona perfeitamente quando não coloco o componente fragment, já quando eu o coloco, o parâmetro `savedInstanceState` do `onCreate()` fica nulo.

XML Main

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".Main"
    android:background="#ff25947a">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="3">

        <ListView
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/listView"
            android:clickable="true" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
        android:layout_weight="7"
        android:id="@+id/layout_direito">


        <fragment
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:name="com.br.estudar.Fragment1"
            android:id="@+id/fragment"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            tools:layout="@layout/layout_fragment_1" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

XML layout do fragment

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"


       android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#ff586abe">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:text="Large Text"
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textSize="30dp" />

    </LinearLayout>
```

JAVA MAIN

```
    package com.br.estudar;

    import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
    import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
    import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.AdapterView;
    import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
    import android.widget.ListView;

    public class Main extends FragmentActivity {

        FragmentManager fm = this.getSupportFragmentManager();
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            String [] lista = new String[]{"Fragment 1", "Altera Texto", "Fragment 2", "Fragment 3"};

            ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new  ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, lista);

            ListView lv = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView);
            lv.setAdapter(adapter);

            lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                    if(position == 1)
                    {
                        Fragment1 frag = (Fragment1) fm.findFragmentById(R.id.fragment);
                        frag.setText("Frag1 - texto alterado");
                    }
                }
            });


  }
}
```

JAVA Fragment1

```
 package com.br.estudar;

    import android.graphics.Color;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
    import android.view.LayoutInflater;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.ViewGroup;
    import android.widget.TextView;


    public class Fragment1 extends Fragment {

        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup conteiner, Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
             View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_fragment_1, null);
             this.setText("Fragment 1");

            return view;
        }

        public void setText(String texto)
        {
            TextView tv = (TextView) this.getView().findViewById(R.id.textView);
            tv.setText(texto);

            this.getView().setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(25, 61, 36));
        }
    }
```

MANIFEST

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.br.estudar">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".Main">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

O erro que ocorre é o seguinte:

```
12-30 16:27:08.517 15362-15362/com.br.estudar E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.os.PersistableBundle', referenced from method com.br.estudar.Main.access$super
12-30 16:27:08.517 15362-15362/com.br.estudar E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.os.PersistableBundle', referenced from method com.br.estudar.Main.access$super
12-30 16:27:08.517 15362-15362/com.br.estudar E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.media.session.MediaController', referenced from method com.br.estudar.Main.access$super
12-30 16:27:08.517 15362-15362/com.br.estudar E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.widget.Toolbar', referenced from method com.br.estudar.Main.access$super
12-30 16:27:08.517 15362-15362/com.br.estudar E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.app.ActivityManager$TaskDescription', referenced from method com.br.estudar.Main.access$super
12-30 16:27:08.527 15362-15362/com.br.estudar E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.app.SharedElementCallback', referenced from method com.br.estudar.Main.access$super
12-30 16:27:08.527 15362-15362/com.br.estudar E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.os.PersistableBundle', referenced from method com.br.estudar.Main.access$super
12-30 16:27:08.527 15362-15362/com.br.estudar E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.app.SharedElementCallback', referenced from method com.br.estudar.Main.access$super
12-30 16:27:08.537 15362-15362/com.br.estudar E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.os.PersistableBundle', referenced from method com.br.estudar.Main.access$super
12-30 16:27:08.577 15362-15362/com.br.estudar E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                Process: com.br.estudar, PID: 15362
                                                                java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.br.estudar/com.br.estudar.Main}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #34: Error inflating class Fragment
                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2318)
                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2396)
                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:139)
                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1293)
                                                                    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:149)
                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5257)
                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:609)
                                                                    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
                                                                 Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #34: Error inflating class Fragment
                                                                    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:707)
                                                                    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
                                                                    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:758)
                                                                    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
                                                                    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
                                                                    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
                                                                    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:290)
                                                                    at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2002)
                                                                    at com.br.estudar.Main.onCreate(Main.java:18)
                                                                    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5411)
                                                                    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2270)
                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2396) 
                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:139) 
                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1293) 
                                                                    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:149) 
                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5257) 
                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793) 
                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:609) 
                                                                    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
                                                                 Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.view.Fragment" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.br.estudar-2.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.br.estudar-2, /vendor/lib, /system/lib, /system/lib/arm]]
                                                                    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
                                                                    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:497)
                                                                    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:457)
                                                                    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:559)
                                                                    at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:652)
                                                                    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:66)
                                                                    at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:669)
                                                                    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:694)
                                                                    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755) 
                                                                    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:758) 
                                                                    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492) 
                                                                    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397) 
                                                                    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353) 
                                                                    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:290) 
                                                                    at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2002) 
                                                                    at com.br.estudar.Main.onCreate(Main.java:18) 
                                                                    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5411) 
                                                                    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087) 
                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2270) 
                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2396) 
                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:139) 
                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1293) 
                                                                    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:149) 
                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5257) 
                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793) 
                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:609) 
                                                                    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Se puderem me deem uma ajuda por favor, Grato desde já.

Comment: Qual é o erro que ocorre?

Comment: O que quer dizer com "savedInstanceState() do onCreate() fica nulo"?. Note que no *XML Main* o atributo deve ser `Fragment` e não `fragment`

Comment: Boa tarde ramaral, primeiramente me desculpe pelo erro, não é savedInstanceState() (um método), mas sim savedInstanceState (um parâmetro do método onCreate()). Eu mudei no meu _XML Main_ o `fragment` para `Fragment` e continuou dando erro. O que acontece é o seguinte, quando a aplicação chama o método onCreate o parâmetro savedInstanceState já vem nulo, que ocasiona diversos erros. O porquê que isso está acontecendo é que não sei, e detalhe isso só ocorre quando eu adiciono a tag `<Fragment>`.

Dener eu alterei o post acrescentando o erro.